# How to escape number inside command-line argument files in java invocation?

Tags: java

Per [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/man/java.html#java-command-line-argument-files):

> You can shorten or simplify the `java` command by using `@` argument files to specify one or more text files that contain arguments, such as options and class names, which are passed to the `java` command. This let's you to create `java` commands of any length on any operating system.
> [...]
>
> The following items describe the syntax of `java` argument files: [...]
>
> - Use the number sign `#` in the argument file to identify comments. All characters following the `#` are ignored until the end of line.

How do I escape the number sign (aka hash character) in a command-line argument file, passed using the `@file` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the argument in double quotes or single quotes. It is desribed in the documentation of environment variable `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`, just before `@file` syntax:

> Single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes can be used to enclose arguments that contain whitespace characters. All content between the open quote and the first matching close quote are preserved by simply removing the pair of quotes. In case a matching quote is not found, the launcher will abort with an error message. [...]

It's not very obvious in the way how the documentation is worded and structured, but `@files` syntax shares these quoting rules with environment variable `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`.

#### Example

`arguments.txt`

```
-classpath *
Sample
arguments with comments # comment is stripped
"argument with the number sign # inside of it"
'another argument with # in it'
```

`Sample.java`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Got " + args.length + " command line arguments");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            String arg = args[i];
            System.out.println("Argument number " + i + ": AAA" + arg + "BBB");
        }
    }
```

When launched as `java @arguments.txt`:

```
Argument number 0: AAAargumentsBBB
Argument number 1: AAAwithBBB
Argument number 2: AAAcommentsBBB
Argument number 3: AAAargument with the number sign # inside of itBBB
Argument number 4: AAAanother argument with # in itBBB
```